# Retrieve text from UITextField using viewWithTag function

Tags: uitextfield, swift2, viewwithtag

I'm trying to retrieve text from a UITextField that I allow the user to create at runtime. I'm using the following line of code.

```
let thisTextField:UITextField = self.scrollView.viewWithTag(0) as! UITextField
```

The compiler error states

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIScrollView' (0x1032faaf0) to 'UITextField' (0x103318dc0).
```

I've looked through stackoverflow and the above code appears to have worked with previous versions of Swift but does not appear to work with Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar issues with this. Since view tags are non optional it would seem that they are initially set as 0. This means that when it looks for a view with the tag 0 it finds the scrollview and returns that. A couple of solutions would be to set the textField to a value other than 0 or make your textField a class variable.